# Java: Handling ' - ' character in custom component text field

Tags: java, components, keyevent

I have a custom text field that only accepts numbers in it.

Everything works fine except when I try to handle the negative (`-`) sign.

```
public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent ev) {

   char c = ev.getKeyChar();
   [...]

   if(c == '-' && getDocument().getLength() > 0 ){ 
      ev.consume();
   }else{
      super.processKeyEvent(ev);
   }
}
```

This works fine when I start with the sign - but not when I already have numbers and want to add a `-` in front.

What I really need is a way to get the position at which this character is inserted but I can't find that.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?"  Fix that caps key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current position inside a text field via the method [`JTextComponent.getCaretPosition()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition%28%29).

It might be easier to fulfill this task with either a [`DocumentListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) or an [`InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) on your text component.

Comment: Thx I was just missing the carret. I had concidered DocumentListner but it felt much to complicated for what I was doing and InputVerifier seems to only control what the user inputed afterwards while I wanted to simply create a number only field.

Answer (score 1):

If your control is a [`TextComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html) or derived from that, you could try using the `getCaretPosition` method to check whether or not the input is being typed at the start of the text.